# Can't canonicalize query :: caused by :: invalid argument in geo near query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Hoping someone can help with this because I've been working on it all morning

I'm trying to use MongoDB Near to find locations within a radius of a given point on a map. I get the following error:

> {"name":"MongoError","message":"Can't canonicalize query :: caused by
> :: invalid argument in geo near query: spherical","$err":"Can't
> canonicalize query :: caused by :: invalid argument in geo near query:
> spherical","code":2,"ok":0}

This is the mongoose schema for locations:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var LocationSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    coordinates: {
      type: [Number],
      index: '2dsphere'
    },
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

mongoose.model('Location', LocationSchema);
```

and this is the route where I try to use "Near" - basically I enter a set of coordinates in a form where the target is the following

```
router.post('/nearme', function (req, res, next) {

// Setup limit
var limit = req.body.limit || 10;

// Default max distance to 10 kilometers
var maxDistance = req.body.distance || 10;

// Setup coords Object = [ <longitude> , <latitude> ]
var coords = [];
// Create the array
coords[0] = req.body.longitude;
coords[1] = req.body.latitude;

// find a location
Location.find({
    'coordinates': {
        $near: {
            $geometry: {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates: coords
            },
            // distance to radians
            $maxDistance: maxDistance * 1609.34, spherical: true
        }
    }
}).limit(limit).exec(function (err, stores) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json(err);
    }

    //res.status(200).json(stores);

    res.render('locations', {
        title: 'Locations',
        location: stores,
        lat: -23.54312,
        long: -46.642748
    });
});
```

Also - I indexed the location collection as follows:

```
db.locations.ensureIndex({ 'coordinates' : '2dsphere'})
```

and as far as I can tell, it looks right:

[image]

Things I've tried:

1. using "geoNear" instead of geometry.
2. removing `spherical:true`
3. searching stackoverflow for similar errors - none seem to have the same issue

Any help you could provide would be amazing. Thank you!

Comment: $near and $geoNear are not the same.  $near does not have an option named spherical

Comment: @Joe Thank you. This is actually code that came out of a book that was published in 2016 so either there has been a change in mongo since then, or there was an error in the book. I'm answering my own question with the solution I came up with after seeing your comment and reviewing the docs. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Joe I reviewed the MongoDB docs and updated the /nearme route as follows (changes made in $near):

```
router.post('/nearme', function (req, res, next) {

// Setup limit
var limit = req.body.limit || 10;

// Default max distance to 10 kilometers
var maxDistance = req.body.distance || 10;

// Setup coords Object = [ <longitude> , <latitude> ]
var coords = [];
// Create the array
coords[0] = req.body.longitude;
coords[1] = req.body.latitude;

// find a location
Location.find({
    'coordinates': {
        $near: {
                $geometry: {
                  type: "Point" ,
                  coordinates: coords
                },
               $maxDistance: maxDistance * 1609.34,
               $minDistance: 0
                    }
                }
}).limit(limit).exec(function (err, stores) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json(err);
    }

    //res.status(200).json(stores);

    res.render('locations', {
        title: 'Locations',
        location: stores,
        lat: -23.54312,
        long: -46.642748
    });
});
```

});